# Using ArrayList properly

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm taking the CS106A course from Stanford and one of the assignments is to build a database of flights available between certain cities. I wrote a class for a city but calling the `addDestination` method  works the first time and when a second destination is added, the `ArrayList` ends up being empty. Why? This one's really got me.

```
import java.util.*;
    //class for a city. destinations are stored in an ArrayList
public class City {

    //Constructor
public City(String name){
    CityName = name;
}

//returns the name of the city
public String getName(){
    return CityName;
}
    // takes in a destination and adds it to the ArrayList unless
    //the destination already exists in which case it returns false.
public boolean addDestination(String destination){
    if (destinations.indexOf(destination)==-1){
        destinations.add(destination);
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

public Iterator<String> destIter(){
    Iterator<String> it =destinations.iterator();
    return it;
}

private ArrayList<String> destinations = new ArrayList<String>();
private String CityName;
}
```

---

Here's the code that creates the database of cities. `hm` is a `HashMap` and it reads a txt file where each line is something like "San Francisco -> New York"

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
     String line = "";
     while (line!=null){
        if (line.indexOf("->")!=-1){
            String From = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("->")-1);
            String To = line.substring(line.indexOf('>')+2);
            City city = new City(From);
            if (hm.containsKey(From)==false)hm.put(From, city);
            hm.get(From).addDestination(To);

        }   
        line = rd.readLine();
    }
```

Comment: don't you mean that you're using the arraylist incorrectly?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but conventional programming etiquette dictates that you put your object variables at the top of the object instead of at the bottom.

Also, you should initialize your destinations ArrayList in the constructor, not in the class itself. That might actually fix your problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you show your calls to `.addDestination()`, and `.destIter()`?

Comment: If you want to have uniqueness of destinetations - Set is more suitable, not ArrayList.

Comment: How do you know the list is empty?

Comment: Hey downvoters, quit it. Just because a newbie doesn't know how to use the right words yet doesn't mean we can't help him with the problem so he will know what words to use in the future.

Comment: HashMaps are the only sets I really know how to use at this point and I don't think that would be appropriate. Edited the post with the calls to addDestination.

Comment: I know the the list is empty using a println on the toString that I didn't include here which iterated through the elements in the ArrayList. Also thanks Tenner! I'm just here to learn what I can.

Comment: @JonAird Code seems ok, the only concern I have is using something returned from the substring command as a key for your hashmap.  Are you sure extra spaces or anything aren't getting added and causing you to create new entries?  Calling .Trim() on From might help some.  Also can you post the code you used to determine the lists were empty?

Comment: Man, I'm dumb! The code works fine but the code I was using to check if it was working fine was flawed (checked destinations from city instead of hm.get(From)). Thanks all especially for the java etiquette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your city destinations list is empty. I debugged your verbatim code and it worked for me.

Double-check to make sure that you're not checking the destinations from `city`, but  `hm.get(From)`. In the case where you have a city you've already found, you're creating a city that you don't end up referring to again.

A somewhat more efficient `while`-block might look like this:

```
while (line != null) {
    if (line.indexOf("->") != -1) {
        String From = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("->")-1);
        String To = line.substring(line.indexOf('>')+2);

        if (! hm.containsKey(From)) {
            hm.put(From, new City(From));
        }
        hm.get(From).addDestination(To);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also a best practice to give your local variables names that begin with a lower-case letter -- e.g., `from`, `to`.

Comment: I was checking destinations from city! Thanks a bunch. It's working fine.

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't mind, please upvote this answer and accept it. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

city contains destinations? I think all that happen because the line `private ArrayList<String> destinations = new ArrayList<String>`, you created a member for the city instance, not the class city, so that means each instance will have a arraylist, but you need only one arraylist to put all the destinations together, it is empty because it's the arraylsit for the second city you created

to be more specifically, I need to see you main method to determine if it's really so.

Comment: The OP was correct; each City has one or more destinations to which one can travel. Therefore each instance of City should have its own ArrayList of destinations.

Answer (score 0):

Other than putting the instance variables on the top your code works for me.